# How to clear a jQuery function from it's values each time it's called

Tags: jquery, html, function

I'm building a website with two types of menus in it, each type has different amount of items. each item will slide 50% of the way when the user clicks the next button, and on the next "next" click, the item will slide 100% to make room for the next item. the next item will be sliding 50% and so on. the "prev" button will do the same, but backwards.
In addition the user can choose which menu type he wants to view, and the animations will be applied to the relevant items.

I have this HTML(& PHP)

```
<div id="menu">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <a href="#cocktails" class="menuanchor"><li>Cocktails</li></a>
        <a href="#kitchen" class="menuanchor"><li>Kitchen</li></a>
    </ul>
</nav>
<ul class="kitchen-box">
    <?php foreach ($kitchen as $item) { 
        echo "<li class='swing'>" . $item["name"] . "</li>";
    } ?>
</ul>
<ul class="cocktails-box">
    <?php foreach ($cocktails as $cocktail) { 
        echo "<li class='swing'>" . $cocktail["name"] . "</li>";
    } ?>
</ul>
<a href="#next" class="next">next</a>
<a href="#prev" class="prev">prev</a>
```

The class swing stores the animation, with the "paused" declaration.
In order to detect which menu type was clicked I'm using the following JS:

```
    $('.menuanchor').click(function() {

    //Getting the current menu type.
    var menutype = $(this).attr("href").replace('#', '');

    //Removes any previous styles no matter which menu was chosen.

    $('.cocktails-box li').removeClass('backwards-animationStart');
    $('.cocktails-box li').removeClass('animationStart');
    $('.cocktails-box li').removeClass('backwards-completeAnimation');
    $('.cocktails-box li').removeClass('completeAnimation');
    $('.kitchen-box li').removeClass('backwards-animationStart');
    $('.kitchen-box li').removeClass('animationStart');
    $('.kitchen-box li').removeClass('backwards-completeAnimation');
    $('.kitchen-box li').removeClass('completeAnimation');
    //Runs the swing function.
    swing(menutype);
});
```

The swing function does the trick that adds the classes to the next/prev list item in the relevant menu. completeAnimation and animationStart are the 50% and 100% animations, and the backward versions are for the prev button to run the items in the opposite direction.

```
    function swing(menutype) {
    //Counting the number of items in the menu.
    var count = $('.' + menutype + '-box').children().length;
    //Always starting the click counts on 1 (so nth-child will start on 1)
    var nextClicks = 1;
    console.log(nextClicks);

    $('.next').click(function () {
        if (nextClicks > 1 && nextClicks <= count) {
            //Runs the next item with a 50% swing and removes previous styles.
            $('.' + menutype +  '-box li:nth-child(' + nextClicks + ')').addClass('animationStart');
            $('.' + menutype +  '-box li:nth-child(' + nextClicks + ')').removeClass('backwards-animationStart');
            //Select the previous element to the nth-child of the user, and removes previous styles.
            $('.' + menutype +  '-box li:nth-child(' + nextClicks + ')').prev().removeClass('animationStart');
            //Select the previous element to the nth-child of the user, and completes the swing to 100% and removes previous styles.
            $('.' + menutype +  '-box li:nth-child(' + nextClicks + ')').prev().addClass('completeAnimation');
            $('.' + menutype +  '-box li:nth-child(' + nextClicks + ')').prev().removeClass('backwards-completeAnimation');
            nextClicks++;
        } else if (nextClicks == count) {
            //Won't let user pass the max list item number.
            nextClicks = count;
        } else if (nextClicks == 1) {
            //Removes previous styles.
            $('.' + menutype +  '-box li:nth-child(' + nextClicks + ')').removeClass('backwards-animationStart');
            //Runs the next item with a 50% swing. - APPLIES ONLY TO THE FIRST ITEM.
            $('.' + menutype +  '-box li:nth-child(' + nextClicks + ')').addClass('animationStart');
            nextClicks++;
        }

    });

    $('.prev').click(function() {

        if (nextClicks == 2) {
            //Removes previous styles.
            $('.' + menutype +  '-box li:nth-child(' + nextClicks + ')').prev().removeClass('animationStart');
            $('.' + menutype +  '-box li:nth-child(' + nextClicks + ')').prev().removeClass('backwards-completeAnimation');
            //If the user clicks prev after selecting ONLY the first item, it will select it and move it backwards.
            $('.' + menutype +  '-box li:nth-child(' + nextClicks + ')').prev().addClass('backwards-animationStart');
            //Won't let the user get to negetive number of items.
            nextClicks = 1;
        }

        else if (nextClicks > 2) {
            //Selects the current list item.
            nextClicks--;
            //Returns the previous list item backwards.
            $('.' + menutype +  '-box li:nth-child(' + nextClicks + ')').prev().addClass('backwards-completeAnimation');
            $('.' + menutype +  '-box li:nth-child(' + nextClicks + ')').prev().removeClass('completeAnimation');
            //Returns the current list item backwards.
            $('.' + menutype +  '-box li:nth-child(' + nextClicks + ')').addClass('backwards-animationStart');
            //Checking if the user already used the prev button.
            if ($('.' + menutype +  '-box li:nth-child(' + nextClicks + ')').hasClass('backwards-completeAnimation')) {
                $('.' + menutype +  '-box li:nth-child(' + nextClicks + ')').removeClass('backwards-completeAnimation');
            }
            $('.' + menutype +  '-box li:nth-child(' + nextClicks + ')').removeClass('animationStart');
        }

    });
}
```

I know this is a really long and ugly code, but it's the best I could make in this specific situation. Everything works fine when the user clicks on a menu type, and uses the next/prev buttons.
**BUT when the user clicking again on the same menu type or a different menu type, and uses the next/prev buttons it seems that the function remembers the old "nextClicks" and "menutype" values and not resetting it each time the function is called.**

Is there any way to clear the whole swing function from it's old values and load it again each time it is being called?

You can check a live example at [boazkerengil.com/zoubisou](http://boazkerengil.com/zoubisou) under the "menu" section (the page is in production so it's messed up and the animations are represented with colors - blue: animationStart, yellow: completeAnimation, orange: backwards-animationStart, purple: backwards-completeAnmiation  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting the click event each time you call the swing function like this :

```
$('.next').unbind("click").click(function() ...});
$('.prev').unbind("click").click(function() ...});
```

Comment: The 3 dots need to be replaced with the whole function's code?

Comment: Yes, the important thing here is to not bind multiple click event on your control. I think this is what create the conflict.

Comment: Alright. So i'll add the following code to the .menuanchor click function. but should I add it before I call the swing function or after?

Comment: You should add it in the swing function for the next and prev click. Assuming that the .menuanchor is done in the document ready, you don't have to unbind it. Only next and prev in the swing function.